# Ruby on rails: Easy way to show text box when a certain dropdown is selected

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now,

I have the below jquery, css and html code which works the way i want. Where If the user selects a dropdown a certain textbox shows. But how can I do it easily in rails?

HTML

```
<form>
    <select id="sel">
        <option value="">- select -</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <label id="label1" for="option1">Text box label 1
        <input type="text" id="option1" />
    </label>
    <label id="label2" for="option2">Text box label 2
        <input type="text" id="option2" />
    </label>
    <label id="label3" for="option3">Text box label 3
        <input type="text" id="option3" />
    </label>
    <label id="label4" for="option4">Text box label 4
        <input type="text" id="option4" />
    </label>
    <label id="label5" for="option5">Other
        <input type="text" id="option5" />
    </label>
</form>
```

CSS

```
label {
    display:block;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(function() {
    //This hides all initial textboxes
    $('label').hide();
    $('#sel').change(function() {
        //This saves some time by caching the jquery value
        var val = $(this).val();
        //this hides any boxes that the previous selection might have left open
        $('label').hide();
        //This just opens the ones we want based off the selection
        switch (val){
            case 'option1':
                $('#label1').show();
                break;
            case 'option2':
                $('#label2').show();
                break;
            case 'option3':
                $('#label1').show();
                break;        
        }
    });

});
```

Rails code

```
<%= f.select(:title, ["Select an option","Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"])%>
```

But I am unsure as to how to show the text box. And the select options I only 3 here. But in my application there will like 10-15.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the Form-Helpers: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a convention between your options and the HTML ids to display.

If your options have a static value, matching an existing label, you could do:

```
$(function() {
    $('label').hide();
    $('#sel').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('label').hide();
        $('#label'+val).show():
    });
});
```

With this you would not have to handle each option, but just add the corresponding option/label id.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the IDs, try to grab the selectedIndex property of the dropdown; indexes start at 0 (zero)

```
var i = getElementById('sel').selectedIndex ;
$('#label'+i).show();
$('#option'+i).show();
```

this is scalable, so it will work if you add options in the future.